# como pasar una hoja .scss a .css?

Tags: css, visual-studio

acabo de instalar sass con ruby installer cmd,ahora como deberia hacer para convertir mi codigo en css y aplicarlo con link en html? ? soy nuevo en los pre procesadores y no encuentro la opcion adecuada para lograr esto, en la pagina de sass econtre muypoca informacion ;(, alguna ayuda ? gracias ! ;D

Comment: No entiendo, ¿quieres que un fichero sass lo pase a scss?

Comment: no quiero utilizar hojas de estilos escritas en visual studio con scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si has instalado sass desde la consola solo tienes que tirar estas lineas en la consola :

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

Ahora vas a obtener el archivo css (output.css) y lo linkeas comunmente en tu archivo index.html. [Te dejo un link](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)

Has escuchado de gulp ?? Yo lo utilizo para correr tareas automaticas a la par que programo, por ejemplo obtener el css del codigo sass de mi codigo. [gulpjs](https://gulpjs.com/)

Comment: gracias!! glup es un editor de texto ?